# How to get specific span text value

Tags: selenium, xpath

How can you get text value of this span using selenium web driver.

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" style="float: left;">
    <span itemprop="name" style="color: #c71d22; font-size: 14px;">
        <b>Das Fiscaal</b>
    </span><br>
```

I tried with this code but it doesn't work. Please any help.

```
String kk = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*div[@itemtype='http://schema.org/LocalBusiness']/div/span[@itemprop='name']")).getText();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the trouble is with your XPath:

You're trying to match a node `*div` which has an **itemtype** attribute, and then trying to find the `div` node underneath this.

Try: `//div[@itemtype='http://schema.org/LocalBusiness']/span[@itemprop='name']`

Which is match a `div` at any level with the correct **itemtype**, then match its direct child `span` with the correct **itemprop.**

Comment: Though also, your `div` is unclosed — presume this is a typo in the question & not your actual code.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, you can read more on XPath syntax here — http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp and you can also debug them using developer tools in most browser consoles with `$x("//my/xpath/here")`

Comment: May i ask one think ? how can i get telefoon nummer of from hier <div style="float: left; color:#c71d22; width: 400px;">&nbsp;<br>
         <span id="telefoon_29284_visible"><a href="#" class="countStatistieken" id="telefoon_29284" style="color:#c71d22;">Klik hier</a></span>
         <span itemprop="telephone" class="hidden" id="telefoon_29284_hidden">010-4765931</span>
        </div>       i use String tel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@itemprop='telephone']")).getText(); give me empty value thank you

Comment: So again, I'd try to debug this first *outside* of Selenium (e.g. through browser dev tools) — see if you can correctly match it on the page itself, that way if you still have issues in Selenium, you can be sure that the fault lies there. At a glance though, your XPath looks OK, but hard to debug in the comments section on SO with no formatting :)